# Obtain JSON output from another script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have implemented the following lines in [this script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwnyiLbLcHbzZf7SsJlLm_o9iZB60w0ubqIg8ldkfg/dev).

```
return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

They return `{"title":"My book","description":"Memories"}` and I can see the URL changing.

I have also written a script to obtain this information. It contains the following line:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(wsURL).getContentText();
```

For some reason, I receive the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <meta name="description" content="Google Drive is a free way to keep your files backed up and easy to reach from any phone, tablet, or computer. Start with 15GB of Google storage – free.">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
        <title>Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files</title>
        <style> @font-face { font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTYnF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf) format('truetype');

            .........................

            }); })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why it is returning this HTML. How can I get my Google script to receive the external script's outputted JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reaching a login page because of incorrect publishing. publish to run as "me", everyone even anonymous. make sure to use versioning. see the official docs about publishing a script for more info.